# ng-bind-html work partially than expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The content contains some image tag and it worked just fine with the `ng-bind-html` but I found bug. See my picture below, my JSON contained some iframe tag but the output isn't output the html. Why? ng-bind-html avoid iframe tags?

[image]

Comment: "See my picture below": what if I can't see images?

Comment: The image is particularly small.  If this is from the console, see if you can select it, then copy/paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngBindHtml` will pass the HTML through `$sce.getTrustedHtml` before displaying it. I suspect this is what would be removing the `iframe`.

According to the docs, `$sce.trustAsHtml` can be used to avoid this check, so long as you fully trust any HTML coming from this source - an `iframe` from an **untrusted** source could likely do a number on nasty things to visitors to your page.

```
$scope.codeOut = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.html);
```

Be very careful with this methodology!

**UPDATE**:

Remember that `$sce` must be included ...

```
var someHTML_Directive = ['$sce', function($sce) {
 ...
}];
```

Comment: Adjusted the answer to give the answer to this ... information here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce