# ng-bind-html removes content after < (less than sign)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, escaping, special-characters, html-sanitizing

I am using angular v1.5.6. I have some user entered html data along with special characters stored in the database. To illustrate,

```
var txt = "<span class='txt_bold'> content with <lessthan signs<span> <span>";

var txt1 = "<span class='txt_bold'> content with <4 lessthan >greaterthan signs <span>";
```

When I put above two lines in ng-bind-html directive I am getting output as below.

```
txt : content with 
txt1 : content with <4 lessthan >greaterthan signs
```

As we can see word after <(less than) sign from the `txt` is removed by directive.
I tried solutions provided in below threads. However, neither of them worked for me to keep html css effect working.

1. [ng-bind-html work partially than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342744/ng-bind-html-work-partially-than-expected)
2. [Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view)

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you put a space between the < and the number/letter it should work

Comment: If you allow users to use HTML tags for formatting user input, you may have to escape the special chars before storing them in the database, so that `txt` becomes `<span class='txt_bold'> content with &lt;lessthan signs<span> <span>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class='txt_bold'> content with <lessthan signs<span> <span>
```

> As we can see word after <(less than) sign from the txt is removed by directive

That is incorrect. The string is actually being parsed as:

```
<span class="txt_bold">
  content with
  <lessthan signs<span>
    <span></span>
  </lessthan>
</span>
```

The `<lessthan` is not being removed; it is being parsed as a `<lessthan>` tag. It is not being removed; it is being rendered as empty.

To escape the parsing use [html entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

```
&lt;lessthan
```

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - innerHTML operational details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Operational_details)

Comment: when I apply escape when saving and put in ng-bind directive instead of ng-bind-html directive it treats unescaped value as a string instead of html.